# Add Top Links on condition basis in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks

I am little bit stuck with adding top links in my custom phtml. I removed the links block in my XML `<remove name="top.links"/>`, now after some condition become true, I want to add this block again. When I use this code for top menu it works but not for links :

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');     
echo $block->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->setTemplate('catalog/navigation/top.phtml')->toHtml();
```

This works and display top menu. But the below code doesn't show anything.

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
echo $block->createBlock('page/template_links')->setTemplate('page/template/links.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Any help?

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: @MagePsycho In my custom phtml

Comment: Instead of <remove> directive, try to use <unsetChild> directive as: <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.links</name></action>, so that you can use it later onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second piece of code actually works but it does not display anything because there are no links attached to the block.
`page/template/links.phtml` starts with this:

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
```

If there are no links there is nothing to display. You need to add links to your block. Something like this:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('page/template_links');
$title = $label = Mage::helper('customer')->__('My Account');
$url = Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl();
$prepareUrl = false;
$urlParams = array();
$position = 10;
$liParams=null;
$aParams=null;
$beforeText=''; 
$afterText='';
$block->addLink($label, $url, $title, $prepareUrl, $urlParams, $position, $liParams, $aParams, $beforeText, $afterText);
//add more links here
echo $block->setTemplate('page/template/links.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Not all parameters are mandatory for the `addLink` method. I just added them here so you can see all the possibilities. For more info take a look at this method: `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links::addLink()`.

Comment: I user your code in my phtml and got this error :Fatal error: Call to a member function addLink() on a non-object in /home/dmagento/public_html/catalog/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/fastlogin/fastlogin.phtml on line

Comment: I edited the answer. it was `createBlock('page/template_link')` and it should be `createBlock('page/template_links')`. I forgot an 's'. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks that works , but for every link i will user addlink code ? Currently only My account displayed

Comment: Yes...You need to add every link. I just added one as an example.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for help I also find another way by event and observer.If anyone interested visit the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706544/add-top-links-on-condition-basis-in-magento)